# Excel VBA works versus Access VBA doesn't

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, web, scrape

This code works perfectly in Excel. It just finds the current price of a coin. However in Access this line

```
 Set container1 = html.querySelector("#productPrice-product-template span:last-child")
```

gives error -2147024809 Invalid argument.

```
Function fncScrapeGOLDvalue() As Integer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Dim returnValue As Integer

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.allgoldcoins.co.uk/products/2013-queen-elizabeth-ii-60th-anniversary-of-the-coronation-5-gold-proof-coin?variant=41603767205941", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim container1 As Object
    Set container1 = html.querySelector("#productPrice-product-template span:last-child")
    
    fncScrapeGOLDvalue = CInt(container1.innerText)
End Function
```

if I modify that line to

Set container1 = html.querySelector("#productPrice-product-template ")

It works!! but it's not exactly what I want

Comment: The line ` Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` fails in Access obviously! Please post the actual code you are using in both Excel and Access.

Comment: Yes sorry. I posted the Excel version. Now corrected.

Comment: It might be due to the limited support of CSS selectors in a mshtml document (`last-child` in this example). And, I think the Excel code also should not work! Use queryselectorall and get the last one in collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dim spans as ihtmldomchildrencollection
set spans= html.queryselectorall("#productprice-product-template span")
fncScrapeGOLDvalue = spans(spans.length - 1).innertext
```

**Update:**

I checked the above code as following and it works:

```
Const url = "https://www.allgoldcoins.co.uk/products/2013-queen-elizabeth-ii-60th-anniversary-of-the-coronation-5-gold-proof-coin?variant=41603767205941"

Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
   
Dim XMLdoc As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
XMLdoc.Open "GET", url, False
XMLdoc.send
html.body.innerHTML = XMLdoc.responseText

Dim spans As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
Set spans = html.querySelectorAll("#productPrice-product-template span")
Debug.Print (spans(spans.length - 1).innerText)

Set html = Nothing
```

But there is something to be considered:
There are actually 2 spans; first has a `aria-hidden=true` which the `QuerySelectorAll` cannot detect (don't know why). The second span has a `class="visually-hidden"` and this is the one in collection.
[image: element inspect in browser developer mode]

I suggest be more specific with CSS selector;
Use this to select the second span:

```
Dim span As HTMLSpanElement
Set span = html.querySelector("#productPrice-product-template .visually-hidden")
Debug.Print (span.innerText)
```

[image: queryselector result]

Comment: Thank you but this returns an object of length zero?

Comment: @BillDowton, I checked the code and it works. Please check the update.

Comment: The addition of  .visually-hidden was exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly! Thank you.